# How to refresh jwt and resend failed http request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, jwt

I have a backend with jwt auth and I want to handle expired tokens.

The following flow is required :

1. Make a request with token attached (and expect a promise)
2. If it goes fine, then just return the promise (and the then/fail method of the caller are executed)
3. If it fails (with 401 unauthorized) then a request is made to refresh the token and token is updated locally
4. If step 3 is successful, return a promise for original request
5. If step 3 fails with 401 (token cannot be refreshed) error redirect to login page

Problem :
In step 4, the original function is called (again) but the caller's then/fail method are not triggered.

Following is my method to append jwt token to the url and send the http request :

```
var AuthenticatedRequest = function(url, data, method) {
  return (function tryRequest(){
    console.log('calling tryRequest');
    return reqwest({
        url: ApiUtil.tokenUrlTo(url),
        method: method,
        crossOrigin: true,
        type: 'json',
        data: data
      })
      .fail(function(err) {
        if (err.status === 401) {
          return post('/auth/refresh-token')
            .then(function(response){
              console.log('assume token set');
              //code to update token locally
            })
            .then(tryRequest)
            .fail(function(err){
              // Can't refresh token. Send to login page
            })
          ;      
        }
      })
    ;
  })();
};
```

And here is the caller :

```
fetchModules: function() {
    get('/admin/modules')
      .then(function(response) {
        Actions.modulesFetchSuccess(response.collection);
      })
      .fail(function(err) {
        Actions.modulesFetchError(ApiUtil.errorArrayForResponse(err));
      })
    ;
  },
```

Now if I get a 401 because the token expired, I trigger a new cycle to refresh the token as suggested in this question [Restart a promise after fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873048/restart-a-promise-after-fail).

Note : `post` and `get` function is just a wrapper around the `AuthenticatedRequest` function with method set to `POST` or `GET`.

The `AuthenticatedRequest` function returns a promise, and if the token is not expired, this runs fine, however, when the token is expired, I get an error in my console and new token is fetched and the function is called again, screenshot of my console - https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJdId.png

But the `then` method of `fetchModules` does not get fired after token is updated. What am I doing wrong ?

Possible Duplicates :

- [AngularJS - Handling refresh token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366678/angularjs-handling-refresh-token)
- [How to resend request when not authorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869690/how-to-resend-request-when-not-authorized)
- [Restart a promise after fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873048/restart-a-promise-after-fail)

**Update September 13, 2015**

[@Bergi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) answer worked when I replaced `reqwest.js` and used `q.js` with vanilla ajax as show in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/matthewp/3099268)

Comment: What promise library are you using, what is `reqwest`? The `fail` method often doesn't chain (e.g. in jQuery)

Comment: @Bergi : I'm using [reqwest.js](https://github.com/ded/reqwest)

Comment: Ah, well, that library doesn't seem to support real promises. It does offer a promise-like interface, but it's not working as one might expect. You should use a proper promise library (choose any) and [cast the `reqwest` to one like here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31327725/1048572).

Comment: If you've chosen a lib, I'd be happy to assist in applying it if you still have problems. Please [edit] your question to add the new information.

Comment: No, I can change the library if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `.fail` is always catching your error, not only the first time. Your recursive call to `tryRequest` will include retries itself, and never return a failed promise.
If you only want one retry, you'll need to put it externally:

```
function AuthenticatedRequest(url, data, method) {
  function tryRequest() {
    console.log('calling tryRequest');
    return reqwest({
      url: ApiUtil.tokenUrlTo(url),
      method: method,
      crossOrigin: true,
      type: 'json',
      data: data
    });
  }
  return tryRequest().fail(function(err) {
    if (err.status !== 401) throw err;
    return post('/auth/refresh-token')
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log('assume token set');
      // code to update token locally
    })
    .then(tryRequest)
    .fail(function(err) {
      // Can't refresh token. Send to login page
    });
  });
}
```

Notice that sending the user to another page from the `AuthenticatedRequest` function might not be a good design, maybe consider just rethrowing the error (after invalidating the token?) and put the redirect and everything in the error handler of the caller.

Comment: I tried this, still the same error, the `caller's` then /fail doesn't get called.

Comment: I replaced reqwest and used your approach with q.js and native XHR. Worked like a charm.

Comment: @ShivekKhurana: Perfect :-)

Comment: Instead of that native XHR function you should also be able to use `function xhr(options) { return Q(reqwest(options)); }` if you need more options.

Comment: I'll keep this in mind and extend it if required. Thank you, you've helped a lot :)